# Вывод массива foreach php

Tags: php, foreach

есть такой код

```
foreach ($_POST['bp'] as $bp)
    echo $bp;
```

`$_POST['bp']` это массив цифр (1, 2, 3).

Как вывести каждую цифру в скобках, что бы было так 
`(1)(2)(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте скобки с помощью конкатенации:

```php
foreach ($_POST['bp'] as $bp) {
    echo '(' . $bp . ')';
}
```

Comment: или без конкатенации `"($bp)"`